# Translate jquery code to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a conflict with jQuery on my website. And my script is in jQuery which is not working correctly.
Please help me to convert this jQuery code to JavaScript. Thank you!

```
         $('.row').each(function(){
         boxes = $(this).find('.product .ic>a');
         maxHeight = Math.max.apply(
             Math, boxes.map(function() {
                 return $(this).height();
             }).get());
         boxes.height(maxHeight);
```

Comment: **What exactyl** does not work?

Comment: So to be clear, you want us to convert this jQuery to plain Javascript?

Comment: perhaps you can tell us which kind of conflict occurs

Comment: You should fix your conflict instead of working your way around it, other problems will occur...

Comment: **Exactyl** (n.) - A very precise pteradactyl

Comment: I have error jQuery(...).FancyMaxiMenu is not a function,
and after that my jquery scripts not work.
I was tryied use "defer" in jQuery init. and jQuery start work, but other scripts  that use jQuery not work

Answer (score 0):

I think it is always better to resolve your conflict [Jquery.noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)**. I would recommend fixing the conflict rather than converting to normal JS** If you still need to convert them, it might look somewhat like this.

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.row')
for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
     boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.row')[i].querySelectorAll('.product .ic>a');
     maxHeight = Math.max.apply(
         Math, boxes.map(function(box) {
             return box.clientHeight;
         }).get());
     boxes.style.height = maxHeight;
}
```

Comment: I have error jQuery(...).FancyMaxiMenu is not a function, and after that my jquery scripts not work. I was tryied use "defer" in jQuery init. and jQuery start work, but other scripts that use jQuery not work –